# Placing a footer dynamic always to bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a website based on bootstrap. every site has unique content and a unique height.

I have a footer and placed it on my index and the result was that:

[image]

Well that was exactly what i needed but then i tried to implement the footer in another site which were shorter and my footer flought in the air.

[image]

As you can see the footer appears after my text but i want to have the footer always on every site at the bottom. If there is not so much text content it should move to the closest bottom position so withou getting scrollbars.

How can i do this?
PS: Im really fresh to html/css

Footer.css

```
.bottom {
    background-color: #474747;
}
.bottom .container {
    background-color: #373737;
    min-height: 130px;
}
.bottom .container h3 {
    color: #999;
}
.bottom .container p {
    color: #666;
}
```

Snippet outside second screenshot

.
.
.

```
<footer>
<!-- Site footer -->
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span> Unternehmen</h3>
                <p>Text Text</br>
                Text Text</br>
                Text Text</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span> Links</h3>
                <a href="Text Text.htm">Text Text</a><br>
                <a href="Text Text.htm">Text Text</a></br>
                <a href="http://icons8.com/">Icons8</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span> Kontakt</h3>                
                  <a href="tel:+">Text Text</a><br>
                  <a href="mailto:mail>Text@text.de</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </footer> 

        <!-- Bootstrap-JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Am Ende des Dokuments platziert, damit Seiten schneller laden -->
    <script src="./js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/

Comment: a fiddle would be nice to have.

Comment: Well Morpheus your comment helped me a lot. So you could do an answer i will accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap already has an example of how to make [sticky footer](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/sticky-footer/).

The basic CSS you need is:

```
body {
    margin-bottom: 60px; /* footer height */
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 60px;
}
```

Comment: @The All Seeing Eye here is the answer

Answer (score 2):

Right now your `.footer` is defaulting to `position: static`, but if you want to always have it at the bottom of the window you need to use `position: fixed` because a `fixed` element is positioned relative to the window.

```
html, body {
  height:100%;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.bottom {
  position:fixed;
  bottom:0;
}
```

However, if you want this to be at the bottom of the page, not the window, use:

```
.bottom {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Change to the following in your CSS

```
.bottom { bottom: 0; background-color: #474747; }
```

Comment: How would `bottom: 0` help if that element doesn't have any `position` associated?

Comment: Yes @Morpheusm is right, you also need a `position: absolute` as part of the style.